# Oracle query sorting ports and labels

Tags: sql, oracle

I can't figure out how to make an oracle query to do the following:

Only the port id's are indexed, all ports are connected left and right.
In the beginning only PORTID_A number 1 is known, so by a simple query i find PORTID_B.
But the ports sometimes start on A and sometimes on B. Like below:

```
PORTID_A    PORTID_B    LABEL
1           2           label-01
2           4           label-02
3           4           label-03
6           3           label-04
5           6           label-05
```

How can get a query result that creates the following:

```
1 <-- label-01 --> 2 <-- label-02 --> 4 <-- label-03 --> 3   etc.....
```

To give a better example from the tabel below, PORTID_A and PORTID_B are indexed.

1. Via a query on PORTID_A = 7742140, i can find PORTID_B, but the next query PORTID_B = 4298763,
   get 2 result lines, one which already found on the first query and the new one.
2. How can i get unique search results as a kind of loop through al to get unique portlabels in correct order like
   like the Result example

```
Table:
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
PORTID_A    PORTID_B    PORTLABEL_A                         PORTLABEL_B
7742140     4298763     00005-ERS10-001/00-0/10-04/1Rx      00005-ODF03-006/06-0/08-0/08
4298763     6853090     00005-ODF03-006/06-0/08-0/08        00005-ODF03-004/02-0/08-0/11
6853497     6853090     00034-ODF03-002/07-0/08-0/11        00005-ODF03-004/02-0/08-0/11
1381299     6853497     00034-ODF03-002/05-0/06-0/03        00034-ODF03-002/07-0/08-0/11
1374115     1381299     00034-ODF03-005/05-0/06-0/03        00034-ODF03-002/05-0/06-0/03
1374115     186966      00034-ODF03-005/05-0/06-0/03        00034-ODF03-005/07-0/04-0/07
24919318    186966      20998-ODF05-002/00-0/01-0/03        00034-ODF03-005/07-0/04-0/07
24919351    24919318    20998-ESU02-001/00-0/00-25/1Tx      20998-ODF05-002/00-0/01-0/03


Result example:
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
00005-ERS10-001/00-0/10-04/1Rx
00005-ODF03-006/06-0/08-0/08
00005-ODF03-004/02-0/08-0/11
00034-ODF03-002/07-0/08-0/11
00034-ODF03-002/05-0/06-0/03
00034-ODF03-005/05-0/06-0/03
00034-ODF03-005/07-0/04-0/07
20998-ODF05-002/00-0/01-0/03
20998-ESU02-001/00-0/00-25/1Tx
```

Comment: Huh?  Not a clue as to what you are asking.  Please edit your question and clarify.

Comment: Forgot the <pre> tags to show a nice table

Comment: Is there cycles or alternate path?

Answer (score 1):

To connect them, I would first solve the problem that portB can be lower than portA:

```
select
  least(PortID_A, PortID_B) as PortID_A,
  greatest(PortID_A, PortID_B) as PortID_B,
  Label
from
  YourTable
```

After that, you can connect them by port id:

```
select
  l.PortID_A,
  l.PortID_B,
  l.Label
from 
  ThatQueryFromAbove l
start with
  l.PortID_A = 1
connect by
  l.PortID_A = prior l.PortID_B;
```

Finally, you can aggregate that to get your result:

```
with 
  VW_LABELS as
    (select
      least(PortID_A, PortID_B) as PortID_A,
      greatest(PortID_A, PortID_B) as PortID_B,
      Label
    from
      YourTable),

  VW_CHAINLINKS as
    (select
      l.PortID_A,
      l.PortID_B,
      l.Label
    from 
      VW_LABELS l
    start with
      l.PortID_A = 1
    connect by
      l.PortID_A = prior l.PortID_B)

select
  '1' || LISTAGG (
      ' <-- ' || c.Label || ' --> ' || c.PortID_B,
      ''
  ) WITHIN GROUP (order by c.PortID_A)
from
  VW_CHAINLINKS c
```

Of course you can combine a couple of these steps to make a shorter query, but to understand the different staps it might be a good idea to keep them separate. The `with` statement is handy to write simple, short queries that work with the result of a previous query.

Comment: I took the liberty to replace the `PortA` alias by `PortID_A` -- as this is the field name used in the rest of the query. Same thing for `PortB`.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Thanks! I typed it in Notepad++, so I could have made other such mistakes.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux and GolezTrol, i tried to add a picture to get a better overview, but i am not able to this. So i give a real table example with Result example what i try to arrange...