# Loop through oracle table via column values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle table where PORT_A and PORT_B are indexed.
In the beginning i only know the value A1 which could be in column PORT_A or PORT_B.
So i query for A1 in (PORT_A,PORT_B) and i find the value B1.
Now i query for B1 but i get 2 rows result:

1. A1 - B1
2. B1 - C1

But i am only interested in the C1 row,
to continue the 'loop' till i reach the end of this 'connection' to get the results.

I'm unable to get the results, in reality those ports are ID numbers not in a specific order.
But to explain my problem, i used A1,B1 etc.. just to show you that they are sometimes only under PORT_A or PORT_B or in both.

```
PORT_A      PORT_B      LABEL_A     LABEL_B
------------------------------------
A1          B1          A           B
B1          C1          B           C
D1          C1          D           C
E1          D1          E           D

The result should be just the unique labels in correct order:

A - B - C - D - E
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle query sorting ports and labels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27474368/oracle-query-sorting-ports-and-labels)

Comment: @Sylvain, in the other question i mention portid's as numbers.
where the solution was based on sorting those numbers first, but in reality those are numbers not in a specific order. I really appreciate the quick answer i got from you (and the time spend) on that question.